# calculate depth of a point using kinect..?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, pcl, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using kinect in ROS. i am working with indigo, ubuntu 14.04. .. my doubt is how can i calculated depth of a point in image. My task is to locate a point in image using mouse and it will tell me the depth of that point.. i already installed openni, pcl. i am also confused of taking which topic i subscribe to calculate depth?
please help me step by step..
language c++

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192529/calculate-depth-of-a-point-using-kinect..??/) by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The topic you are looking for is the `depth/image_rect` topic published by the openni stack, which you start via `openni_launch` (if you're using the kinect). This will be a rectified 2D image, with the intensity of the pixel representing the depth at that point.

As for displaying the image, try taking a look at the `image_view` node.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-09-13**:
thanks a lot.... but this time i got a new problem... on indigo, i am not sure but openni is not installable....

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-13**:
If you're having issues installing openni, I'd suggest you open a new question, with some debug output to boot.